# How to call a function X after N hours

Tags: go, time

```
func (timeTables) GetTimeTables(c echo.Context) error {

    resp, err := http.Get("url")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    test := &models.MultiModel{}
    json.Unmarshal(body, &test)
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK,"")
}
```

how to call func GetTimeTables after 1 hour , i use AferFunc , What am I missing ?

```
func (timeTables) CallFunc() {
    time.AfterFunc(4*time.Hour, func() {
        GetTimeTables(c echo.Context)
    })
}
```

Comment: `GetTimeTables(c echo.Context)` is not a valid function call, you have to pass a value of type `echo.Context`, it is used to interact with an HTTP request which you won't have after `x` hours. Who do you want to send an HTTP response to? If no one, `GetTables()` shouldn't require an `echo.Context` in the first place.

Comment: It's not gonna work that way. You will need to do the `GetTimeTables` in a background/cron job

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to block, otherwise, it will exit before the `AfterFunc` is triggered.

Try removing the sleep from this example https://play.golang.org/p/_25RffWDyPV to see.

`GetTimeTables` is not a function that can be called directly, you need to call it as a method of the timeTables object.  Also as mentioned by @icza, you should be passing a value to the function.

Something like this should work:

```
func (t timeTables) CallFunc(c echo.Context) {
    time.AfterFunc(4*time.Hour, func() {
        t.GetTimeTables(c)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see `c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "")` there, so I assume the code is a route handler (with echo framework used).

If what you wanted to try is this: for every incoming http request, wait for 4 hours then run the `GetTimeTables()`; then you http request will fail because of timeout.

Also `time.AfterFunc` will be executed asynchronously (as goroutine), so the http request will be finished before the callback executed.

Probably please tell use in details what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I do myAPI with echo framework , myAPI will call to orther API by func GetTimeTables . Your mean is :

```
func (t timeTables) CallFunc(c echo.Context) {
    time.AfterFunc(4*time.Hour, func() {
        t.GetTimeTables("myAPI")
    })
}
```